# Create a database on PostgreSQL via a command line

Tags: database, postgresql, command-line-interface, psql

I'm trying to **create database** in psql via CLI.

```
psql  -U postgres createdb portal
```

I kept getting

```
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "portal" ignored
psql: FATAL:  database "createdb" does not exist
```

What did I do wrong ?

---

## Note

I'm not trying to **queries** any data.

Comment: Spend 5 minutes reading the man page, please.

Comment: I'm not trying to **query from a command line**, I'm trying to **create** a database. That answer is **NOT** what I am looking for. Please kindly unmark it.

Comment: Please try `psql -U postgres -c "CREATE DATABASE portal;"`

Comment: Finally, someone know what I am trying to do. Thanks @code_onkel

Comment: @code_onkel : Your suggestions works perfectly. Please answer it, you deserve it. :)

Comment: `createdb` is an OS binary/executable. `create database` is a SQL command

Comment: @ihue Actually, Vao Tsun was even faster.

Comment: psql  -U postgres -c  "create database portal"  or https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-createdb.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

here I connect as user `vao` to database `postgres` (which always is there) and create database `db1` in `CLI`... The first argument without key is database name, so in your example `createdb` is interpreted as dbname to connect to...

please look at [documentation of psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html)

```
Vaos-MacBook-Air:tts vao$ bash -c "psql -U vao postgres -c 'create database db1;'"
CREATE DATABASE
```